# When exchanging keys between source and target systems, does local account have to exist on a remote system as well?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

Full rephrase:

Local system server_local has an account username_local. I am logging under this account, generate a public key and send it to the remote system server_remote, where it is added to the username_remote@server_remote:${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_hosts

Neither local system nor remote system allows easy UID manipulation, so we can't create usernames on either host.

Will this be sufficient to connect to the remote system via

```
sftp username_local@server_remote 
or
sftp server_remote 
or
sftp username_remote@server_remote
```

EDITs:

a) by 'authenticate remotely' I meant access the remote server using key pairs exchange while executing the call **sftp username_local@server_remote** and going through a trusted connection, with a password skipped

b) I think Torin already answered the second question that the suffix in the key file is merely a comment, so changing it won't affect a thing

CONCLUSION:
Worked like a charm in the **sftp username_remote@server_remote** format. Thank you gentlemen!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "send it to authenticate remotely"? As in send the public key file to `server_remote` from `server_local` using sftp? Also, note that the `username_remote@server_local` in `ssh-rsa ...... username_remote@server_local` is actually a comment, it exists only for making clear which key is which and doesn't mean anything to ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sftp server will look in the remote home directory

```
~username_remote/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

if the
local private key matches the public key in `authorized_keys`, so

- `sftp username_local@server_remote` won't work unless `username_local` equals `username_remote` since there is no matching user on the remote side
- `sftp server_remote` same as above
- `sftp username_remote@server_remote` works if you have the matching private key in your local `~/.ssh` directory (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) which is then offered and accepted by the remote side for authentication.

It's irrelevant which local user you are if you have access to the private key (identity_file) and pass it as an argument like this

```
sftp -i identity_file username_remote@server_remote
```

to the sftp command. It's like a key in the real world.

The local user account doesn't have to exist remotely, but it's convenient if local and remote user are the same and you can simply use `sftp server_remote`.